# How Timer command works in HEXCHAT

Tags: command-line, command, irc, hexchat

there is a command that I can't use...
anyone knows the correct syntax?

```
Usage: TIMER [-refnum < num >] [-repeat < num >] < seconds> < command>
        TIMER [-quiet] -delete < num>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/timer 10 say This is 10 seconds later!`

`/timer -repeat 3 10 say I am repeatedly saying this 3 times in 10 sec intervals`

`/timer -refnum 1 -repeat 0 10 say I repeat this until the end of time!`

`/timer -delete 1` (This stops the previous one)

Just typing `/timer` will list any that are running if you didn't specify a refnum.

Answer (score 1):

```
/timer -repeat -1 9 nick myNick
```

or

```
/timer -repeat 999999999999 9 nick myNick
```

it only gets executed once then it's gone from the timers list